# Lambda@edge redirect gets in a redirect loop

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have a static website on aws s3. Have setup route 53 and cloud front and everything works smoothly. s3 Bucket is setup to serve index.html as index document.

Now I have added another file called index-en.html that should be served when the request country is any other country and not my home country.

For this I have added a lambda@edge function with the following code:

```
'use strict';

/* This is an origin request function */
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;

    /*
     * Based on the value of the CloudFront-Viewer-Country header, generate an
     * HTTP status code 302 (Redirect) response, and return a country-specific
     * URL in the Location header.
     * NOTE: 1. You must configure your distribution to cache based on the
     *          CloudFront-Viewer-Country header. For more information, see
     *          http://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/cloudfront/cache-on-selected-headers
     *       2. CloudFront adds the CloudFront-Viewer-Country header after the viewer
     *          request event. To use this example, you must create a trigger for the
     *          origin request event.
     */

    let url = 'prochoice.com.tr';
    if (headers['cloudfront-viewer-country']) {
        const countryCode = headers['cloudfront-viewer-country'][0].value;
        if (countryCode === 'TR') {
            url = 'prochoice.com.tr';
        } else {
            url = 'prochoice.com.tr/index-en.html';
        }
    }

    const response = {
        status: '302',
        statusDescription: 'Found',
        headers: {
            location: [{
                key: 'Location',
                value: url,
            }],
        },
    };
    callback(null, response);
};
```

I have also edited cloud front behavior to whitelist Origin and Viewer-country headers and setup the cloudfront Viewer-Request event and lambda Function ARN relation.

However I get a "too many redirect error".

I have 2 questions:

1. How to correct the "too many redirects error"?
2. For viewers outside "TR" the default landing page should be index-en.html, from which 2 more pages in english are accessible via navigation menu. So when users request a specific page from page navigation they should be able to access those pages, when no page is requested the default landing page should be served.

Appreciate help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a redirect loop because you are sending the viewer back to the same site, same page, no matter what the results of your test.

```js
if (countryCode === 'TR') {
    return callback(null, request);
} else {
...
```

`callback(null,request)` tells CloudFront to continue processing the request -- not generate a response.  Using `return` before the callback causes the rest of the trigger code not to run.

Comment: Will this redirect users where countryCode is not TR always to the index-en.html no matter what page they request?

Comment: You can't redirect users "no matter what page they request" unless you first verify that they did not request the page you're planning to redirect them to -- that is why you have a redirect loop.  It was not clear from your question that **all** requests should go to a single page.  You may need to clarify your question with an edit, describing exactly what behavior is expected under varying conditions.

Comment: I have made an edit to the original question. Thank you for all the help.